# Pourquoi met on le mot "bien" ici dans cette phrase?

Tags: ordre-des-mots

J'ai un ami qui apprend le français, et je ne pouvais pas lui expliquer pourquoi on dit:

```
Je peux bien comprendre cela
```

et que cette phrase sonne moins bien

```
Je peux comprendre cela bien
```

Est ce qu'il y a une règle officielle? et est ce que la 2e phrase est fausse?

Comment: Ca me rappelle une blague dans un vieil Almanach Vermot : 
- Cette fille est super belle, je lui ferais bien l'amour.
- Non, tu lui ferais volontier l'amour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le placement de "bien" *change le sens de la phrase*. C'est beaucoup plus marqué avec le verbe *veux*:

> Je veux bien comprendre cela

"Bien" **exprime la bonne volonté**: "I'm willing to (try to) understand that".

> Je veux comprendre cela bien

"bien" a le sense de "correctement, adéquatement": "I want to understand well/correctly" (quoiqu'on utiliserait rarement un pronom démonstratif ici car c'est redondant)

On peut aussi expliquer qu'en français, le premier cas applique l'adverbe à l'auxiliaire uniquement, et le second au verbe principal. En anglais, ce n'est pas possible sans carrément employer un verbe auxiliaire différent.

Remarque que dans les dans les deux cas on emploierait de toute façon plutôt un adverbe comme *correctement* ou *exactement* pour la seconde phrase.

Comment: Je ne suis pas du tout d'accord avec le 'fait que je veux bien comprendre cela' exprime la volonté.Sans contexte 'Je veux bien comprendre cela' peut se comprendre à la fois 'je (veux bien) comprendre' ou 'je veux (bien comprendre)'.  En aucun cas on utilisera je veux compendre cela bien. En absence de contexte, on aura un gros risque de quiproquo (voir la blague de mon commentaire de la question).